# Exclude files only in "release" in VS2008 config

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, release, release-management

I was wondering how to "Exclude" individual files in the "release" web.csproj config of my solution. I've seen other answers and they all feature "include" - but this is not what I am wanting to achieve. I only want to exclude around 10-15 files from a "release" package ?

I don't want to manually edit the web.csproj file - so is there any way I can do this via web.config or ?

How would I go about doing this ?

Comment: I've never used web projects, but or C++ projects you can right-click any file in the solution explorer and set 'Excluded from Build'; maybe that works for web as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding files is global unfortunately (I don't know of a way to achieve it directly).

A workaround for this would be to enclose the contents of the files in

```
#if DEBUG
   ...
#endif
```

to conditionally exclude the contained code from the build.